# Is there a way to programmatically encrypt custom fields?

Tags: metadata-api, shield-encryption

For standard fields, we can do it via Setup (Setup > Encryption Policy > Encrypt Fields), then we get a list of all available fields and we can tick the box for each one.

But for custom fields, do we really need to go to each field one-by-one and set it as encrypted?
I have hundreds of custom fields that I need to encrypt,
is there a way to do it via the metadata API or any other tool?

Comment: MDAPI should work fine

Comment: @cropredy I was not able to find any documentation about it, can you link an article pls?

Comment: It will be a CustomField within a CustomObject metadata type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have tagged the question for [shield-encryption](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shield-encryption) I assume that is what you want, rather than [classic encryption](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/fields_about_encrypted_fields.htm).

As cropredy commented, you will have the [CustomField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customfield.htm) metadata. In particular, you want these two metadata fields:

- `encrypted`

> Indicates whether this field is encrypted (true) or not (false). This field is available in API version 34.0 through 43.0.

- `encryptionScheme`

> For encrypted fields, determines which encryption scheme a field takes. Valid values are None, ProbabilisticEncryption, CaseSensitiveDeterministicEncryption, and CaseInsensitiveDeterministicEncryption. This field is available in API version 44.0 and later.

It would probably be easiest to do one or two fields manually to see what metadata changes are required to enable the encryption. Then just replicate that out to any other fields you want to enable it on. Exactly how you do this with the Metadata API will depend on your setup. E.g. If you are using the SFDX CLI to deploy the scratch org format metadata it would be reasonably easy as you will already have the required files ready to modify.

If you are defining the org shape directly in a sandbox you will need to retrieve the required metadata (possibly by defining a package.xml file). And then you need to deploy the changes back to the org.